# Google supports SO

Tags: discussion

I am using google to find answer to my questions (because stackoverflow search is *"too specific"*).

Since today I see something new:

---

[image]

---

I apologize for no freehand circles.

My questions are:

- is it made by google without asking SO team?
- how useful is this "crap" (yes, it's crap)?
- how to turn it off?

Comment: If this is made by google, I highly doubt you will be able to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks @rene, though I am a bit confused of why I didn't see it before.

Comment: I had a hard time to find it myself , so I hope this duplicate will be a better sign-post ...

Comment: @rene: the oldest one we have is [Is Google doing something new with this site's data?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268731), but since I was overridden by the community on the one you did find and Joe Friend answered, the one you found is now the canonical-ish post on the subject.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ha, I see you have had an enjoyable experience on that Q/A. Still recovering I guess ... ;)

Comment: @rene, I mean I see those things for the first day in the google. They are pretty annoying and SO was the first thought to contact (because maybe guys here can tell google to stop doing it). Are you guys agree it's useless? The amount of information provided is not enough not to **use as an answer**, nor to decide **which** answer to use. I'll have to visit SO page **anyway**, so why the hell google bothered?? As a result I see **less** search results or have to scroll more and this drives me nuts.

Comment: @Sinatr Google does try to become a one stop shop by providing answers to your questions in their search results, like they attempted here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s71ef.png.  It is bound to fail ...